# tinymce is undefined in plugin development using npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, tinymce-4

I used on my Mac OS X exactly the way it is described [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/yeoman-generator/).

My page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector:'textarea',
      plugins: 'myplugin',
      toolbar: 'myplugin'
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Testing myplugin</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

So i do `npm start` and `webpack 2.7.0` starts on port 8080. The browser opens and I see my textarea.

But I get `tinymce is undefined`.

Checking the source and click the link I can see the resource is available.

For testing I moved the tinymce folder into the `static` folder and changed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

but I get this error then:

```
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/tinymce/tinymce.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

I am new using `npm` so it has probably something todo with my setup. Can anyone advise?

Comment: What are you using to serve web content?  Express/Node?  Something else?

Comment: I am not sure I get what you ask. I just installed npm stuff and generated a example plugin for tinymce and did everything described in the tutorial. But starting it fails finally. As I am not familiar with webpack I just guess that the /static/ folder is the web-root of the example.

Comment: What web server is running your code? When people mention node and webpack that would normally mean you are relying on something like Express or Hapi to be your web server. The resource error you get would typically mean that you are not properly serving up the files from that location or your URL is not correct.

Comment: Well all I do is `npm start` which do this `webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.config.dev.js --progress --open --inline`.

Comment: Really stupid, it turns out that it was blocked by some firefox security plugin :S. My bad.